# Angular 2 Release "Unexpected value 'ElementRef' imported by the module"

Tags: javascript, angular

I upgraded to the release of Angular 2 and I am trying to use ElementRef. At first, I got the error `Angular2 RC5 error:zone.js: Unhandled Promise rejection: No provider for ElementRef` as specified here: [Angular2 RC5 error:zone.js: Unhandled Promise rejection: No provider for ElementRef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38926004/angular2-rc5-errorzone-js-unhandled-promise-rejection-no-provider-for-element) so I changed my code to:

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, ElementRef }       from '@angular/core';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [DashboardComponent, WidgetBankComponent, DataTableDirectives, OrderBy],
    exports: [DashboardComponent, WidgetBankComponent],
    imports: [BrowserModule, HttpModule, FormsModule, ChartsModule, ElementRef],
    providers: [ChartService, GridService, WidgetsControlService, GridViewService, ApplicationSettingsService, DataService, ToolsService, LocalStorageService, RuntimeCompiler, COMPILER_PROVIDERS, NgGrid, NgGridItem],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
```

and now I am getting the error `(SystemJS) Unexpected value 'ElementRef' imported by the module 'DashboardModule'`

any ideas?

Thank you in advance!

EDIT

Did the suggested fix in the answer below and now have this error - here is the full error - is there a way to tell where i need to supply the provider from this error?

```
zone.js:355 Unhandled Promise rejection: No provider for ElementRef! ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: NoProviderError {_nativeError: Error: No provider for ElementRef!
    at NoProviderError.Error (native)
    at NoProviderError.Base…, keys: Array[1], injectors: Array[1]}_nativeError: Error: No provider for ElementRef!
    at NoProviderError.Error (native)
    at NoProviderError.BaseError [as constructor] (http://localhost:56159/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:1248:38)
    at NoProviderError.AbstractProviderError [as constructor] (http://localhost:56159/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:1703:20)
    at new NoProviderError (http://localhost:56159/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:1734:20)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (http://localhost:56159/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:3331:23)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (http://localhost:56159/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:3359:29)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (http://localhost:56159/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:3322:29)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.get (http://localhost:56159/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:3131:25)
    at NgModuleInjector.AppModuleInjector.createInternal (AppModule.ngfactory.js:310:75)
    at NgModuleInjector.create (http://localhost:56159/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:7192:80)constructResolvingMessage: (keys)injectors: Array[1]keys: Array[1]message: (...)name: (...)stack: (...)__proto__: AbstractProviderError Error: No provider for ElementRef!
    at NoProviderError.Error (native)
    at NoProviderError.BaseError [as constructor] (http://localhost:56159/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:1248:38)
    at NoProviderError.AbstractProviderError [as constructor] (http://localhost:56159/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:1703:20)
    at new NoProviderError (http://localhost:56159/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:1734:20)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (http://localhost:56159/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:3331:23)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (http://localhost:56159/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:3359:29)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (http://localhost:56159/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:3322:29)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.get (http://localhost:56159/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:3131:25)
    at NgModuleInjector.AppModuleInjector.createInternal (AppModule.ngfactory.js:310:75)
    at NgModuleInjector.create (http://localhost:56159/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:7192:80)consoleError @ zone.js:355_loop_1 @ zone.js:382drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:386ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:308
zone.js:357 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for ElementRef!(…)consoleError @ zone.js:357_loop_1 @ zone.js:382drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:386ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:308
```

Comment: which version of angular2 are you using?

Comment: the final release

Comment: its strange! it should work. Which zone.js version are you using in final version?

Comment: `^0.6.25` is my zone version. I am also using the ng2-charts and ng2-grid libraries, which I think might be calling ElementRef somewhere, so I was thinking I might be able to just include it everywhere

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove `ElementRef` from `imports` array and paste it into array of `providers`:

```
import { NgModule, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
@NgModule({
    declarations: [DashboardComponent, WidgetBankComponent, DataTableDirectives, OrderBy],
    exports: [DashboardComponent, WidgetBankComponent],
    imports: [BrowserModule, HttpModule, FormsModule, ChartsModule],
    providers: [ChartService, GridService, WidgetsControlService, GridViewService, ApplicationSettingsService, DataService, ToolsService, LocalStorageService, RuntimeCompiler, COMPILER_PROVIDERS, NgGrid, NgGridItem, ElementRef],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
```

Comment: that creates the same error as in the original posting :(

Comment: @blubberbo, you run `tsc` from your root project folder?

Answer (score 0):

use it at **individual component level** where you need it.

```
import {  ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
 ....
})
export class DashboardComponent{
    constructor(private el:ElementRef){}
}
```

Comment: then i get `zone.js:355 Unhandled Promise rejection: No provider for ElementRef! ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: NoProviderError`... which leads me to believe i am referencing it somewhere, but i have no idea how to find out where. it might be a plugin i have, so i wanted to try and add it as a provider for all plugins

Comment: remove `ElementRef` from `imports` and do as I said.

Comment: I removed it from the imports and i added it to the component like you said, and now i get `no provider...`